# Opening RDA file (R file)

Tags: r

I am trying to open and see the data in an R file (`.rda`) but it gives me error:

```
library("ETAS")
vars <- load("jap.quakes.rda")
vars
```

This is the error msg:

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'jap.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: It is always good to show the error message you are getting, then it is easier for others to help you. Also when you show code remember to put four spaces in front of each line of code to make it prettier and easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to load the data `jap.quakes` from the ETAS package. What your code now does is to load the `jap.quakes.rda`, which probably is not there (you can check with `dir()`).

Since you want to load data from a package just do:

```
data(jap.quakes)
```

This is also stated in the documentation of the package.

Now the object `jap.quakes` is available in your global environment. Type `jap.quakes` to show the object.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want to see the data and if it allows me, edit the data.

Comment: Try `?jap.quakes` for a description of the data. Also see `?str` which is a functions that shows you the structure of an object.

Comment: After you load some data using `data`, you have your local copy. You can do whatever you want with this copy. Of course the data in the package are not changed, if you remove your copy and load the data again, you will have the original version. In order to save your edits you can use `save`, e.g. `save(jap.quakes, file="myjapquakes.Rda")`

Comment: I used data(jap.quakes) and then jap.quakes, but it just give me the summary of the data, it doesn't show the data..

Comment: It just gives me this:Multidimensional point pattern
13724 points 
2-dimensional space coordinates (long,lat)
1-dimensional time coordinates (time)
3 columns of marks: ‘mag’, ‘depth’ and ‘date’ 
Domain:
        Box: [0, 29943] x [128, 145] x [27, 45] units

Comment: You can use functions like `class` (what class is the object, here it is `ppx`) You can also use names to see if the object has some named elements, here there is an element `data`. You can access that using `jap.quakes$data`. In general use `str`, `class`, `names`, `head` to see how an object look like and what it contains. Use ? to get help about specific functions or data, e.g. `?head`.